# Push Array React Native Keep Replace And Not Append

Tags: javascript, react-native

What is the correct way to use push array in React native ?

```
const BuilderIndicatorCard = (props) => {
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
    const [checkedValue, setCheckedValue] = useState([]);
    
    let storeCheckedValue = [];
    useEffect(() => {    
        if (isChecked) {
            storeCheckedValue.push(props.indicator);                                                      
        }                                    
        console.log(storeCheckedValue);      
    }, [isChecked, checkedValue])
    
    

    // const removeCheckedStrategy = (checkedValue, array) => {
    //     var copyArray = [...array]; 
    //     var index = copyArray.indexOf(checkedValue);
    //     if (index !== -1) {
    //         copyArray.splice(index, 1);
    //         setArray(copyArray);
    //     }
    // }

    return (              
        <CheckBox           
            containerStyle={styles.checkbox}
            size={15}  
            textStyle={styles.name}       
            title={props.indicator}
            checked={isChecked}
            onPress={() => {setIsChecked(!isChecked)}}
        />                            
    );
};
```

When I do **storeCheckedValue.push(props.indicator);** why the array keep replace and not append ?

**This is show in the console :**

```
Array [
  "Price Below MA (5)",
]
Array [
  "Price Below MA (7)",
]
Array [
  "Price Below MA (9)",
]
```

did I miss something in here ?

Comment: Can you add what `props.indicator` value is?

Comment: Price Below MA (5)

Price Below MA (7)

Price Below MA (9)

Price Below MA (10)

Price Below MA (14)

Price Below MA (15)

Comment: @ShahanshahAlam that's all checkbox value in props.indicator

Comment: When I tick the checkbox it should push and set an array value

Comment: try to go through this https://appdividend.com/2022/01/30/javascript-array-push/#:~:text=To%20add%20an%20array%20into,an%20element%20into%20the%20Array.
I guess you are pushing array into array. You should push a string or an object.

Comment: @ShahanshahAlam I use checkbox element from here https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/1.2.0/checkbox and I just get the chekbox value and push it to array, I try to make dummy function push array and add Math.random() to array. but the result is replacing not appending

Comment: @ShahanshahAlam do you have specific answer or solution for this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a proper way to solve my question above.
This is how I did it.

I use redux-toolkit

Create a slice like :

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
    

const addChecked = (state, action) => {
    state.indicator = [...state.indicator, action.payload];
}

const removeChecked = (state, action) => {
    state.indicator = state.indicator.filter(data => data != action.payload);
}

// status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed',
export const BuilderSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'Builder',   
    initialState: {        
        indicator: [],
        status: 'idle',
        error: null
    },
    reducers: {
        addCheckedIndicator: addChecked,
        removeCheckedIndicator: removeChecked
    },   
    extraReducers: {                        
    }
});


export const { addCheckedIndicator, removeCheckedIndicator } = BuilderSlice.actions
```

Then In the card component I change to like this :

```
import { addCheckedIndicator, removeCheckedIndicator } from '../redux/slice/builder/BuilderSlice';
const BuilderIndicatorCard = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const data = useSelector(state => state.Builder.indicator);   
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(true);   
    

    const addValue = useCallback(() => {                   
        setIsChecked(!isChecked);             
        if (isChecked) {
            dispatch(addCheckedIndicator(props.indicator));                    
        } else {
            dispatch(removeCheckedIndicator(props.indicator));            
        }                            
        
    }, [isChecked]);

    

    return (              
        <CheckBox           
            containerStyle={styles.checkbox}
            size={15}  
            textStyle={styles.name}       
            title={props.indicator}
            checked={props.checked}
            onPress={() => {addValue()}}
        />                            
    );
};
```

I dispatch the function in slice in here:

**dispatch(addCheckedIndicator(props.indicator));

dispatch(removeCheckedIndicator(props.indicator));**

And then make sure use :

```
const addValue = useCallback(() => {
        
    },[second]);
```

Not **useEffect.**